# undefined method `translations' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree

Im working on an app based on spree with several addons.
When using heroku I receive a HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error.

```
undefined method `translations' for nil:NilClass
```

Development environment on localhost is working. Only after pushing to heroku I receive this error.

heroku log (edited)

```
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572469+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572469+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572469+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572469+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__347425213395248139__call__callbacks'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572469+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572469+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.573291+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.573291+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-09T16:04:14.604783+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
2013-10-09T16:04:14.573291+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.573291+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.604783+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
2013-10-09T16:04:14.573291+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.573291+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.573291+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.573291+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-09T16:04:14.739784+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=warm-tor-1570.herokuapp.com fwd="54.225.15.95" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=208ms status=500 bytes=21198
2013-10-09T16:04:14.535855+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 54.225.15.95 at 2013-10-09 16:04:14 +0000
2013-10-09T16:04:14.542105+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35mSpree::Page Load (1.6ms)[0m  SELECT "spree_pages".* FROM "spree_pages" WHERE "spree_pages"."visible" = 't' AND (("spree_pages"."slug" IS NULL OR "spree_pages"."slug" = '/')) ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1
2013-10-09T16:04:14.544130+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "spree_pages".* FROM "spree_pages" WHERE "spree_pages"."visible" = 't' AND (("spree_pages"."slug" IS NULL OR "spree_pages"."slug" = '/')) ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1[0m
2013-10-09T16:04:14.535855+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 54.225.15.95 at 2013-10-09 16:04:14 +0000
2013-10-09T16:04:14.545620+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "spree_pages".* FROM "spree_pages" WHERE "spree_pages"."visible" = 't' AND (("spree_pages"."slug" IS NULL OR "spree_pages"."slug" = '/')) ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1
2013-10-09T16:04:14.547785+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Spree::HomeController#index as */*
2013-10-09T16:04:14.544130+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "spree_pages".* FROM "spree_pages" WHERE "spree_pages"."visible" = 't' AND (("spree_pages"."slug" IS NULL OR "spree_pages"."slug" = '/')) ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1[0m
2013-10-09T16:04:14.545777+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "spree_pages".* FROM "spree_pages" WHERE "spree_pages"."visible" = 't' AND (("spree_pages"."slug" IS NULL OR "spree_pages"."slug" = '/')) ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1
2013-10-09T16:04:14.542105+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[35mSpree::Page Load (1.6ms)[0m  SELECT "spree_pages".* FROM "spree_pages" WHERE "spree_pages"."visible" = 't' AND (("spree_pages"."slug" IS NULL OR "spree_pages"."slug" = '/')) ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-09T16:04:14.559828+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mSQL (1.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT DISTINCT "spree_taxons".id, "spree_taxons"."id" AS alias_0 FROM "spree_taxons" LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_taxon_translations" ON "spree_taxon_translations"."spree_taxon_id" = "spree_taxons"."id" WHERE "spree_taxon_translations"."name" = 'Slider' AND "spree_taxon_translations"."locale" = 'de' AND (spree_taxon_translations.name IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY "spree_taxons"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `translations' for nil:NilClass):
2013-10-09T16:04:14.561469+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/spree_fancy-3a8a1796e8ef/app/controllers/spree/home_controller_decorator.rb:4:in `index'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]:   (eval):2:in `first'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]:   (eval):2:in `tap'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.561325+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567453+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:493:in `_run__3801270098307990630__process_action__callbacks'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]:   (eval):4:in `block in first'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567453+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568269+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.547612+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Spree::HomeController#index as */*
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568269+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568961+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__347425213395248139__call__callbacks'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568269+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568961+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570558+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/spree_fancy-3a8a1796e8ef/app/controllers/spree/home_controller_decorator.rb:4:in `index'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568269+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.559828+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mSQL (1.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT DISTINCT "spree_taxons".id, "spree_taxons"."id" AS alias_0 FROM "spree_taxons" LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_taxon_translations" ON "spree_taxon_translations"."spree_taxon_id" = "spree_taxons"."id" WHERE "spree_taxon_translations"."name" = 'Slider' AND "spree_taxon_translations"."locale" = 'de' AND (spree_taxon_translations.name IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY "spree_taxons"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
2013-10-09T16:04:14.568764+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.569436+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.567247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570558+00:00 app[web.1]:   (eval):2:in `first'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.569651+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570558+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571568+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570558+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `translations' for nil:NilClass):
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571718+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571568+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571568+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570558+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570942+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571718+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.569651+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571568+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.569651+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571718+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570768+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571568+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572469+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570768+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570768+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571718+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571718+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.571718+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570558+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.570942+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.572916+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-09T16:04:14.736039+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (143.3ms)
2013-10-09T16:04:14.721602+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (4.7ms)
2013-10-09T16:04:14.735805+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.5ms)
2013-10-09T16:04:14.735805+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.5ms)
2013-10-09T16:04:14.721684+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (4.7ms)
2013-10-09T16:04:14.735924+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (143.3ms)
2013-10-09T16:01:41.314983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
```

Production.rb

```
    Farmfood::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true #false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false #true

  #set host amazon
  ActionController::Base.asset_host = "http://bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # config/environments/production.rb
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

ruby '1.9.3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# database gem for convertion sqlite3 to postgresql
gem 'yaml_db'
gem 'pg'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# Include amazon file upload
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

#fix issue Undefined variable: "$c_green"
gem 'compass'
gem 'compass-rails'

#necessary for spree_i18n (translation tool)
gem 'globalize3', github: 'svenfuchs/globalize3', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'paper_trail', github: 'airblade/paper_trail', branch: 'master'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'spree', '2.1.1'
gem "spree_social_products", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_social_products.git", :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_fancy', :github => 'spree/spree_fancy', :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem "spree_social", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_social.git", :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree/spree_i18n', :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_static_content', :github => 'spree/spree_static_content'


#group :development, :test do
#  gem 'sqlite3'
#end

#fix heroku
gem 'rails_12factor'#, group: :production
#group :production do
#  gem 'pg'
#end
```

Comment: You have an uninitialized object (basically a nil pointer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it using Ryan Big's fix:

```
gem 'spree', :github => 'radar/spree', :branch => '2-1-stable'
```

The fix will be made available on the spree/spree repository soon, I hope. If you want to read the whole discussion around this issue, see [this post](https://github.com/spree/spree_i18n/issues/301).

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `translations` on something that's evaluating to nil. It might be working locally because you're relying on the presence of something in your session or development db that won't be there when you try to access it on heroku.

edit: I don't see any mention of the error itself in the log you posted. Is there any more to it? You might want to temporarily change `config.log_level` to `:debug`, try loading the page again, and then reposting the logs.

---

OK, I'm not really familiar with Spree but I *think* the issue is in the `index` method in `home_controller_decorator.rb`. In that method, are you calling `translate` on an object? If so, are you certain there's no way that object is nil? I'd probably use something like pry in this circumstance to check things out.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic but this was the first result in Google for my error.

Don't use "cookies" as a method in your controller because it is reserved for cookie use :)